# What is need of $timeout here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
createRequest = function(endpoint, params, data) {
    var xdr = new $window.XDomainRequest();
    var x2js = new xml2Json();
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onerror = function() {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.reject(xdr.responseText);
                });
            };
            xdr.onload = function() {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    var jsondata;
                    if (xdr.responseText) {
                           deferred.resolve(jsondata);    
                    } else {
                        jsondata = "No data";
                    }
                });
            };
            xdr.open("post", urlMaker(endpoint, params));
            if (data) {
                var requestData = serviceFactory.requestTranform(data);
                xdr.send(requestData);
            } else {
                xdr.send();
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

1. What is the purpose of `$timeout` here? Removing it is failing the ajax calls and also is 2ms sec needed?

Answer (score 0):

The `$timeout` makes sure the call gets made asynchronously and the `2000` actually means that it will be executed 2 seconds later. You could probably remove the `2000` so it will be executed as soon as possible but it needs to be run asynchronously for this code to work.

The `deferred.promise` takes care of returning an eventual object that will be availalbe after the ajax call has been completed.

Comment: Can i remove the 2000 completely and set it to 0, does it make any sense to delay it 2 seconds and also why does this code need to run asynchronously?